# Xamarin Plugin.BluetoothLE await characteristic notification

Tags: xamarin, promise, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to write one nice, tidy "login" function that I use to log in to a bluetooth peripheral by sending it a password.

```
public async Task<bool> LogIn()
{
    bool result = false;

    //First log in 
    var connectHook = Device.ConnectHook(BleService.Control, new Guid[] { BleCharacteristic.PasswordResult });

    connectHook.Subscribe(ScanResult =>
    {
        ScanResult.Characteristic.DisableNotifications();

        //Succesful Login
        if (ScanResult.Data[0] == 1)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        //Failed Login
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
    });

    await Device.WriteCharacteristic(BleService.Control, BleCharacteristic.Password, PasswordBytes);

    await connectHook.FirstAsync();

    return result;
}
```

I basically want to subscribe to the password result characteristic, then write the password, and then wait for the password result before returning from the function.

Is this the place to use a promise? I have read about them but do not understand their use.

Thanks

EDIT:

Did some digging and think I've found a good answer. I've updated the code above to reflect it, let me know what you think.

EDIT 2:

So, the code above doesn't work because nothing is returned from

```
await connectHook.FirstAsync();
```

If I comment that line out it all works....but it seems like it's working because I have a race condition and the notification gets back before the other code completes.

Does the function magically await for that notification? I thought the observable implemented IEnumerable and would return the first item as long as it had come back? I'm new to this reactive stuff so please be kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code:

The method `connectHook.Subscribe` is a asynchronous method. Before you added the two `await` methods, the function `login` will directly return false without wait the callback in `connectHook.Subscribe`,so the return value in `login` will not be changed whether you login successfully or failed to login.

After you add the two `await` methods,I guess the callback in `connectHook.Subscribe` has been triggered after these two methods finished running. So the return value will be changed with the return value in the callback.

Comment: what you've said is right and I've learned quite a bit more since I asked this question. I've tried asking again here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449757/how-to-subscribe-to-iobservable-sequence-force-completion-and-retrieve-all-dat