# How to Subscribe to IObservable Sequence, force completion, and retrieve all data without race conditions

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, rx.net

There is a pattern I'm having trouble with when working with observables.

I am working with a bluetooth device.

1. I send a message to that device telling it to do something and notify me of the result or results.
2. The device starts sending notifications (could go for 10ms or 20s)
3. I wait for the device to finish sending notifications. sometimes this will be a specific message from the device and sometimes I just won't receive any more messages for a timeout period.
4. I convert the messages to a single item or an IEnumerable and go on my merry way.

Example one:

1. I enter a login command with a login message and a password
2. The device sends back a success or failure message (usually 10ms or so)
3. I wait for the message to come
4. I use the message to tell if the user can continue or if they need to retry their password.

Example two:

1. I send a command to the bluetooth device requesting all wifi networks in range
2. The device turns on its wifi radio and sends back an unknown number of messages but stops at some point
3. I wait for the messages to stop
4. I present the complete list of wifi networks to the user

I think this should be done in this something close the following manner. (I've removed as much bluetooth specific code as possible to help focus on Rx):

```
//Create a new subject
Subject<int> subject = new Subject<int>();

//Observe the subject until some pre-determined stopping criteria
bool waiting = true;
IObservable<int> sequence = subject.TakeWhile(x => waiting);

//Subscribe to the subject so that I can trigger the stopping criteria
IDisposable subscription = sequence.Subscribe(
                onNext: result =>
                {
                     if (result > 50)
                        waiting = false;
                },
                onCompleted: () =>
                {
                     return;
                });

//fake bluetooth messages
int i = 0;
while (i < 100)
    subject.OnNext(i++);

//Gather them all up once the sequence is complete
//***application hangs here***
List<int> ints = await sequence.ToList() as List<int>;

//This line of code is never run
subscription.Dispose();
```

I'm hoping that an Rx guy can help me understand why this ToList() call hangs. I just wrote this code on the spot for this question so if it doesn't make sense let me know and I'll update it.

Here is the actual code that uses a third-party bluetooth library and receives items from a bluetooth device.

```
    private static async Task<byte> WritePasswordToPeripheral<P>(P Peripheral, byte[] command) where P : Peripheral, IStatePeripheral
    {
        IGattService service = await Peripheral.RPHDevice.GetKnownService(BleService.Control);
        IGattCharacteristic characteristic = await service.GetKnownCharacteristics(BleCharacteristic.PasswordResult);

        //I know that this TakeWhile isn't necessary here because I'm using FirstAsync() later on
        //In some similar blocks I receive multiple notifications and so I need to decide when to stop listening in this way. 
        //In those situations I would call .ToList() instead of .FirstAsync()
        bool waiting = true;
        await characteristic.EnableNotifications().TakeWhile(x=>waiting);

        IObservable<CharacteristicGattResult> passwordResultSequence = characteristic
            .WhenNotificationReceived();

        IDisposable passwordResultSubscription = passwordResultSequence 
                                                    .Subscribe(
                                                    onNext: result =>
                                                    {
                                                        waiting = false;
                                                    },
                                                    onCompleted: () =>
                                                    {
                                                        return;
                                                    });

        try
        {
            await Peripheral.RPHDevice
                    .WriteCharacteristic(BleService.Control, BleCharacteristic.Password, command)
                    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        //In this case only one notification ever comes back and so FirstAsync would be nice
        var passwordResult = await passwordResultSequence.FirstAsync();
        await characteristic.DisableNotifications();
        passwordResultSubscription.Dispose();

        return passwordResult.Data[0];
    }
```

WhenNotificationsReceived:

```
    IObservable<CharacteristicGattResult> notifyOb;
    public override IObservable<CharacteristicGattResult> WhenNotificationReceived()
    {
        this.AssertNotify();

        this.notifyOb = this.notifyOb ?? Observable.Create<CharacteristicGattResult>(ob =>
        {
            var handler = new EventHandler<CBCharacteristicEventArgs>((sender, args) =>
            {
                if (!this.Equals(args.Characteristic))
                    return;

                if (args.Error == null)
                    ob.OnNext(new CharacteristicGattResult(this, args.Characteristic.Value?.ToArray()));
                else
                    ob.OnError(new BleException(args.Error.Description));
            });
            this.Peripheral.UpdatedCharacterteristicValue += handler;
            return () => this.Peripheral.UpdatedCharacterteristicValue -= handler;
        })
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();

        return this.notifyOb;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the actual issue/question is here.

Comment: Good question. The line: List<Message> messages = await messageObserver.ToList() hangs. I've clarified the question above.

Comment: What is `messageObserver` ?

Comment: This is probably easy to fix if you make reproducible code. Please post a [mcve]. I can't run or compile this.

Comment: And to be clear, the problem has probably nothing to do with bluetooth. Calling Rx with await is normally wrong. See if you can replicate the issue using `Subject`s.

Comment: @Petaflop messageObserver should have been messageSequence.

Comment: @Shlomo I am working on that now.

Comment: @Eric - The `.ToList()` operator is waiting for the observable to complete before it can return the values. If it doesn't complete it doesn't return.

Comment: @Eric - You need to allow the observable to properly end to get the results. The `.TakeWhile(Func<T, bool>)` overload depends on getting a value for the observable to end and depending on what thread it is running on that might be a race condition for your code. You haven't given us a [mcve] so we can't tell for sure.

Comment: @Eric - What is the signature for `bluetoothdevice.WhenNotificationReceived()`?

Comment: @Enigmativity that signature is from a third party bluetooth library, I've almost got a working sample that just uses Subject

Comment: @Eric - Yes, can you post the actual signature?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have added some code that includes actual bluetooth calls but it doesn't use WhenNotificationReceived. I'll work on that and post it asap.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have added the requested signature and updated my bluetooth-included code sample to be a reflection of what I think should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a bunch of problems with your code.

First up, Rx is an asynchronous programming model that you're trying to run synchronously. Calling `await sequence` (and similarly `sequence.Wait()`) will cause you grief almost all of the time.

Next, you're creating two subscriptions to the `sequence` observable - once with the `sequence.Subscribe(...)` and again with the `await sequence.ToList()`. They are separate subscriptions to the underlying `subject` and they need to be treated as separate.

And finally, you're mixing external state (`bool waiting = true`) into your query `subject.TakeWhile(x => waiting)`. That's bad as it is inherently non-thread-safe and you should code as if your query is running on multiple threads.

What is happening with your code is that the `await sequence.ToList()` is subscribing to your query **AFTER** you have pumped out your `subject.OnNext(i++)` values so the query never ends. No value is ever pushed out of the subject **AFTER** the `.ToList()` to trigger the `.TakeWhile(x => waiting)` to end the observable. `.ToList()` just sits there waiting for the `OnCompleted` that never comes.

You need to move the `await sequence.ToList()` to before you pumped out the values - which you can't do because it would still get stuck waiting for for the `OnCompleted` that never comes.

This is why you need to code asynchronously.

Now the two subscriptions also causes you a race condition. The `sequence.Subscribe`might set `waiting` to `false` before the `sequence.ToList()` gets any values. This is why you should code as if your query is running on multiple threads. So to avoid this you should only have one subscription.

You need to lose the `.TakeWhile(x => waiting)` and push the condition inside like this: `subject.TakeWhile(x => x <= 50);`.

Then you write your code like this:

```
//Create a new subject
Subject<int> subject = new Subject<int>();

//Observe the subject until some pre-determined stopping criteria
IObservable<int> sequence = subject.TakeWhile(x => x <= 50);

sequence
    .ToList()
    .Subscribe(list =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", list));
    });

//fake bluetooth messages
int i = 0;
while (i < 100)
    subject.OnNext(i++);
```

This code runs and produces `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50` on to the console.

Don't write Rx code synchronously - lose the `await`. Don't run multiple subscriptions that could create race conditions. Don't introduce external state into your queries.

Also, with the `WhenNotificationReceived` method, you're not properly completing the sequence.

You're using the dangerous `.Publish().RefCount()` operator pair which creates a sequence that can't be subscribed to after it completes.

Try this example:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Take(3)
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();

var s1 = query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

Thread.Sleep(2500);

var s2 = query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

Thread.Sleep(2500);

s1.Dispose();
s2.Dispose();

var s3 = query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

Thread.Sleep(2500);

s3.Dispose();
```

This only produces:

```
0
1
2
2
```

The `s3` subscription produces nothing. I don't think that this is what you're after.

Comment: WhenNotificationReceived is source from a third-party library, should I make changes to it and make a pull request?

Comment: You tell me not to run Rx code synchronously, but at some point I have to wait for these messages to finish. The simplest case is that of a password. I am entering a password, and then I need to wait for a result before I can continue. How do I do that in the Rx paradigm?

Comment: Based on your feedback I'd like to simplify the question. Should I edit the question above or mark yours as answer and ask a new question?

Comment: I got mine working thanks to your guidance so I've marked as answer. I don't want to be overbearing with my questions......I'm just so new at Rx!!!

Comment: @Eric - You don't have to block your code to wait for the messages to finish. Just have your code run in a call-back.

Comment: @Eric - Always leave the current question and ask a new one.

Comment: Hi Enigmativity! Could you clarify this sentence please? *"You're using the dangerous .Publish().RefCount() operator pair which creates a sequence that can't be subscribed to after it completes."* I am not able to reproduce it ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H5D38O)).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I think you reproduced it precisely. See that your second subscription didn't output `Produced #1`. I really need to track down, via the source, what going on with this operator combo, but it can, in some circumstances, produce a query that will only produce a `OnCompleted` signal and other times it restart the original source. Unless I'm missing something, it's buggy. I always prefer the `.Publish(xs => ...)` overload.

Comment: Yeap, you are right, I got what you mean before a while. Its behavior is not consistent regarding reconnecting to the underlying cold observable. I want to investigate further if the culprit is the `Publish` or the `RefCount`. Probably I'll post a question about it later.

Comment: I posted a question about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961330/how-to-fix-the-inconsistency-of-the-publish-refcount-behavior "How to fix the inconsistency of the Publish().RefCount() behavior?").